# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I have a this model

```
public class Task
{
    public Task() { }

    public Task(int CategoryID)       
    {         
        this.TaskID = CategoryID;  
    }       

    public int TaskID { get; set; }
}

public class student
{      
    public List<Task> Task { get; set; }      
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

In My controller there is an error which says: `'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`

```
student student = new student(); 
var TaskQuery = from q in db.tblTasks
                select new
                {
                    TaskID = q.TaskID,                                
                };

qaTaskQuery = qaTaskQuery.OrderBy(x => x.TaskID );

foreach (var StudentTask_ in TaskQuery)
{
    student.Task.Add(new Task()  //Getting error
    {
        TaskID = StudentTask_.TaskID 
    });
}
```

Please tell me what is wrong with my code??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Youy have not instantiated `List<Task>`:

```
student.Task = new List<Task>();
foreach (var StudentTask_ in TaskQuery)
{
   student.Task.Add(new Task()  //Getting error
   {
     TaskID = StudentTask_.TaskID 

   });
}
```

or you can do this in **constructor** of `Student` class:

```
public class student
{      
   public List<Task> Task { get; set; }      
   public string Name { get; set; } 
   public int ID { get; set; }

   public Student()
   {
     this.Task = new List<Task>();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to initialize your Task list before you add something to it:

```
public class student
{      
    public student()
    {
       Task = new List<Task>();
    }
    public List<Task> Task { get; set; }      
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```